# Problems with wwan0 interface

Tags: usb, modem

I am trying to connect to a 4G LTE network using Huawei E3372 modem. 
`ifconig` shows a `wwan0` interface when the modem is connected.
This is what it looks like:

```
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:b7:f0:cb:22:c2
          inet6 addr: fe80::d47d:591e:63c:8136/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8057 (7.8 KiB)
```

And `lsusb` gives me this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:2c27 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:157c Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10c4:8103 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However , I am not able to connect to the internet using this , I tried wvdial and sakis3g but they failed. How do I find the port of this device? How do I configure the APN? Please Help.

Comment: Someone on Amazon reports using a Huawei USB modem with a Raspberry Pi, but could not do it via the `wwan` interface until he/she used `qmi-network`.  Unfortunately there's not a lot of documentation about that online, but it does have a texinfo manual if you install the package (see the end of `man qmi-network` about that...`info` based docs are a bit awkward...).

Comment: Hey when I run this command `sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start` I get this: `root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
Loading profile...
    APN: airtelgprs.com
Starting network with 'qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wds-start-network=airtelgprs.com  --client-no-release-cid'...
error: couldn't create client for the 'wds' service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out
error: network start failed, client not allocated`